# Unknown Type Name CGRect in function(not method) declaration

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, cgrect

I am trying to declare a function in an `NSObject` type class to be called for some core graphics drawing.  How do you properly declare a function in objective c?
I'm not doing anything complicated, something like...

in **.h**

```
void drawShape(CGRect rect);
```

however this throws an  `unknown type name 'CGRect'` error.  And I dont know why being that its in the `applicationservices.h`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CGRect` is part of the CoreGraphics framework; therefore, you must ensure to include it in your app.

Comment: It is, I use it all over the place.

Comment: Add the header to your file getting the compile error and see if the issue is fixed.  My guess is it will.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you forgot to import the CoreGraphics header.

I could compile this code on the *command line* using `clang` without an error:

```
#include <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>

void drawShape(CGRect rect);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't link the `CoreGraphics.framework` with your project.  `CGRect` is defined in `CoreGraphics` framework.

Comment: you don't actually need to link CoreGraphics.framework if you just need the CGRect struct. Importing the header is enough.